# dynamic images meta tag based on user choice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to share the image based on the user choice I have created that but it does not work on the share. I am using `react helmet` to setup the meta tags also `react snap`. For the sharing I am using `react share`
I have a slider and the chosen image will be shared on social media I can see the update on the meta tags when I inspect the page but when I share it only shows the default image.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8400931/103488008-c911ef00-4e09-11eb-8661-2b1f96386cc4.mp4

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-leaf-lsv9t

Check out the link. Thank you

Comment: Please give us a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The question is clear and It is challenging to provide a reproducible example when things are related to share and meta data. I have included a link above u can see the changes happening only i cant share those changes instead it only shares the default image.

Comment: "It is challenging to provide a reproducible example when things are related to share and meta data." We want your code, not a video showing your code.

Comment: I have included an example link in the question

Comment: Is it okay if you accept my answer to that question you asked earlier about the Carousel?

Comment: I just did thank you for your help on Carousel question? I would prefer if you can write a detailed answer so others can benefit as well?

Comment: I finished adding a edit explaining the code.